# How to query websphere node status from Linux CLI

Tags: linux, websphere

Is there a way to verify Websphere Node status from Linux CLI using one of IBM shell scripts?

I've been using this way to get this information from CLI since i did not find a script that does this for me, but i get an 500 error since i did not login yet to DMGR (After login this will result with an answer:

wget "http://ap0tv01tap01ndsw0.ap0tv.tas.att.net:9060/ibm/console/status?text=true&type=node&node=ap0tv01tap02mlsw0"
--2013-07-04 18:00:07--  http://ap0tv01tap01ndsw0.ap0tv.tas.att.net:9060/ibm/console/status?text=true&type=node&node=ap0tv01tap02mlsw0
Resolving ap0tv01tap01ndsw0.ap0tv.tas.att.net... 172.20.31.12
Connecting to ap0tv01tap01ndsw0.ap0tv.tas.att.net|172.20.31.12|:9060... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2013-07-04 18:00:07 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.

Alternative solution for me could be triggering what Web login triggers to operation system and do it from CLI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [serverStatus](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_serverstatus.html) command to query status of node agent. You may use both `nodeagent` as server name as an argument or use `-all` flag. If security is enabled in your cell don't forget to specify username and password as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
serverStatus gives me Node Agent status as STARTED\STOPPED. I would like to query of the Node is Synchronized or Not Synchronized:

Comment: Determining the synchronization status of a node using wsadmin: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21178926